# what does a ! b mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, operators

I am reading through some Scala code and part of the program reads as follows:

```
clusterManager ! ClusterManagerMessages.Shutdown
clusterNotificationManager ! ClusterNotificationMessages.Shutdown
```

I see that ! is a unary operator so what does this code mean?

Comment: ! is logical NOT operator http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_operators.htm

Comment: @geedubb thanks but the TutorialsPoint site only shows the unary case.

Comment: In this context it is most likely a fire-message instead of the logical operator.

Comment: what is a fire-message?

Comment: @La-comadreja Don meant "a fire-and-forget message," as opposed to asking and waiting for a response.  BTW, thanks for teaching me how to say "weasel" in Spanish.  :^)

Answer (score 7):

In scala language nothing (in your context), but it is usually means *fire-n-forget message* in [scala actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/hello-world.html). There is also `?` counterpart which is used when you want to have handle to the response in a form of Future.

Answer (score 5):

The `!` operator is shorthand for the `tell` method in Scala Actor APIs.  The [Scaladoc for akka.actor.ActorRef](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/#akka.actor.ActorRef) provides two examples, one for each of Scala and Java.  Notice how Java uses the `tell` method and Scala uses the `!` operator.

On a personal note, I found it particularly frustrating when I was first researching Scala actors and found no explicit definition of the binary `!` operator in the Scaladocs.  The best resource that I have found so far for being introduced to Scala Actors is [Programming in Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531644) (Ch. 32) by Odersky et al.  If you have the time and/or dedication to gain an in-depth understanding of the Akka Actor model and what's going on beneath the hood, I recommend [Akka in Action](http://www.manning.com/roestenburg/).

Comment: It took me years to learn how to correctly spell `tell` in high school. I'm glad, someone finally took care of that hassle `!`

Comment: Scala Actors are deprecated.

Comment: @Ryan that sounds familiar, but can you provide a link?  The [latest Scaladoc for 2.10.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.Actor) does not provide any indication of deprecation.

Answer (score 3):

`!` is not, in this case, a unary operator. If you see code like this in Scala:

```
a b c
```

then that's most likely the `b` method being called on the `a` object passing `c` as parameter. And it doesn't really matter whether `a`, `b` and `c` are words or symbols -- Scala accepts both.

In this particular case, `!` means "send message", so `clusterManagement ! ClusterManagementMessages.Shutdown` means send the message `ClusterManagementMessages.Shutdown` to the actor `clusterManagement`. For more information on what *that* means, look up information about the actor model.

Answer (score 0):

So much complexity in the answers so far!

In this context, it's most certainly the (unsynchronized) message-send operator, not the unary negator operater, and it's used in the semi-standard Akka library. If you're not familiar with them, read up on Scala "Actors" and how systems can be built with loads and loads of small "actors" that communicate with each other via message sending. In this case, the code is appears to be telling a "clusterManager" to shut down, and then sending a "clusterNotificationManager" the message that it's told the clusterManager to shutdown.